# Why is do-support omitted in the negation "and lean not on your own understanding"?

Tags: negation, do-support

I'm puzzled by the following negation in [Proverbs 3:5, New King James Version](https://my.bible.com/bible/114/PRO.3.NKJV):

> 5. Trust in the Lord with all your heart,
>    And **lean not** on your own understanding;

As far as I know, that should be **do not lean**; not using do-support is considered archaic, so I'm not surprised to see it in the King James Version, but the NKJV is from 1982. (For what it's worth, the NIV, whose latest revision is from as recent as 2011, has the same construction.)

Moreover, a couple of verses later, do-support *is* used:

> 11. My son, do not despise the Lord’s discipline,
>     and do not resent his rebuke,

What is happening here? Can this construction (not using do-support) be used for emphasis, was the King James Version so well known that recent translators opted to retain this construction, is the verb 'lean' somehow considered an auxiliary or copular verb here, or something else entirely?

Comment: The Lords Prayer uses it: _And lead us not into temptation_. It's consciously archaic now, and it was when it was written, too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is the New King James Version is meant to be as close to the King James Version as possible while remaining readable to modern English speakers. Hence, ye's and thou's are removed because most English speakers don't know how to conjugate them (or even what situations you're meant to use them in), but the formation verb + not can be kept or removed, since we still use it for verbs like can and will.

As for why the formation verb + not is used in this particular instance, the reason is that Proverbs 3:5 in the King James Version is a very popular verse, so the editors probably wanted to keep the wording the same.

Comment: FWIW, the KJV uses 'despise not' in verse 11.

Answer (score 1):

Likely, this is done so that the two conjucts ("trust..." and "lean...") each start with an imperative, making them a bit more parallel; this sounds a bit better than it would with do-support. That change isn't useful in the second example, where both conjuncts can have do-support.

The lack of do-support is common in old texts and proverbial expressions (e.g. "waste not, want not").

Answer (score 0):

By way of example, "i think not" is described as a formal way of saying, "i disagree". It could be inferred then that other verb negations of this sort might be accepted usages to represent a different form of negation. In this case, "i think not" is an ornate form of "i disagree". "I don't think" is a standard way of saying "no". Very similar intents but these are two distinct meanings and are used to respond to different challenges or questions.

[Cambridge Dictionary - "I think not"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-think-not)

Applying this to the given example, i interpret the passage to mean "lean, but not on your understanding (lean on what you are commanded previously to trust)". This is somewhat distinct from the meaning of "do not lean on your understanding", which is clearly bad advice in general without combining it with a better alternative.